# emacs haskell mode can't remember change tag

Tags: haskell, emacs

I'm fresh to emacs haskell, and struggle the problem for a week ago.
For detail, another file can't see the changed tag when I change a tag in new file.The config process is mainly by [serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md) on github.
the gif as below:
1) Main.hs: ref `mac` function in Lib.hs
2) Lib.hs: will change `mad` function to `mac`
**result**:
Main.hs can't get the changed tag `mac` in Lib.hs

[image]

thanks any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use intero. It's designed for emacs, and for stack.

Comment: thanks your advice but intero also has the trouble. I can't get the changed tag. Should I do a further config?

Comment: With intero, you can move through tags by tagging system of intero itself, there is no such problem

Comment: I.e. if you experience any such problem  , it is not from intero, but from other plugin you installed for haskell.